# Why IE8 is redirecting me to it redirects to http://.fls.doubleclick.net/ when I try to open a specific page of my website

Tags: internet-explorer, redirect, double-click

Why IE8 is redirecting me to it redirects to http://.fls.doubleclick.net/activityi;src=4300794;type=execclub;cat=baexespa;ord=1438923046491? when I try to open a specific page of my website.

Resetting the IE8 is fixing this issue, but I cannot force my users to reset their IE8. Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: What does "resetting IE8" mean?

Comment: Internet Exploper 8 is IE8

Comment: Reset means to : 1.Close all Internet Explorer and Windows Explorer windows that are currently open.
2.Reopen Internet Explorer.
3.Click the Tools button, and then click Internet options.
4.Click the Advanced tab, and then click Reset. ...
5.In the Reset Internet Explorer Settings dialog box, click Reset.
6.Close and open the Internet Explorer.

Comment: If that is happening then it sounds like *your* system has been exploited somehow; hopefully it is not from this website - if it is, it could mean that the website has been compromised as well and is 'infecting' others! That behavior and 'fix' should never happen in any browser. Make sure to enable and run anti-virus and anti-malware and install the latest updates. Remove all unknown BHO's and extensions. Updating IE8 would probably be advisable too ..

Comment: Could you please explain a more bit, how can I resolve this issue so that there will not be any requirement to reset IE by the users end. I do not want to enforce user to do any setting for my site, what is the route cause of this issue, any malware in network or in system or anything else? Should I have to contact to doubleclick.net support team [if any]?

Comment: Issue is only in IE8 remain all browsers are behaving well for that certain page.

Comment: It is a local exploit that may or may not be propagated by the website being visited. If it is *not* propagated by this website (eg. it might have come from elsewhere or via another malware route) then visitors to such will likely not have this problem, even in IE8; but if it *is* due to an exploit in the site then that will need to be corrected, lest it affects other vulnerable systems. You will have to analyze the site (ie. make sure all content is authorized) over the requests made. It is *not* doubleclick that is doing this, but rather someone *using* the doubleclick service.

Comment: My recommendation is then to 1) run anti-virus and anti-malware software locally (*this is to clean the local system and protect you*, and possibly eliminate the observed problem); and 2) ensure the site has not been tampered with and there is no foreign content that could propagate this exploit (*this is to protect the site visitors*, and you in the future).